# Generate xml from ruby classes with namespaced nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, object, mapping

I have a ruby class like this:

```
class MyResponse
    attr_accessor :results
    def initialize(results = nil)
        @results = results
    end
end
```

With this code,

```
resp = MyResponse.new 'Response text'
qname = XSD::QName.new('http://www.w3schools.com/furniture', :MyResponse)
xml = XSD::Mapping.obj2xml(resp, qname)
puts xml
```

I managed to generate this xml from that class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<n1:MyResponse xmlns:n1="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <results>Response text</results>
</n1:MyResponse>
```

But I would like the `<results>` node also to have the namespace prefix like `<n1:results>`

I am trying figure this out for a long time. Please help me out.

Edit: I just need all the nodes to have namespace prefix. I'm open to any other way or libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I love to read and write XML with [ROXML](https://github.com/Empact/roxml). Unfortunately the documentation is not complete, although can retrieve many informations directly from the [code documentation](https://github.com/Empact/roxml/blob/master/lib/roxml.rb). I did not succeed in giving an example that exactly meet your requirements (the xmlns node is only xmlns not xmlns:n1) but maybe you can complete it:

```
require 'roxml'

class Response
    include ROXML

    xml_name 'MyResponse'

    xml_namespace :n1

    xml_accessor :xmlns, from: :attr
    xml_accessor :results, from: "n1:results"

    def initialize
        @xmlns = "http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"
    end

end

response = Response.new
response.results = "Response text"
puts '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'
puts response.to_xml
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
# <n1:MyResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
#   <n1:results>Response text</n1:results>
# </n1:MyResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantically speaking, you don't need to prefix every node with the namespace prefix, in order to make them all member of the same namespace.

This XML is, for all purposes, equivalent for your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <results>Response text</results>
</MyResponse>
```

With that in mind, you can use `Builder` to wrap the `Response` XML into that (assuming it implements the `to_xml` method – all `ActiveModel` classes do):

```
b = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new
xml = b.MyResponse :xmlns => 'http://www.w3schools.com/furniture' do
  b << resp.to_xml
end
```